# How to access a variable from inner class

Tags: objective-c

```
 //MainClass.m 

 @interface InnerClass : NSObject{

 }
 @end

 @implementation InnerClass

 -(void)run{
      while(isActive){//want to access this variable which defined in MainClass
      //do something
      }
 }

 @end

 @interface MainClass : NSObject{
      BOOL isActive;
 }
 @end

 @implementation MainClass


 @end
```

I have MainClass and it has an inner class (InnerClass). I want to access the boolean type variable (isActive) defined in MainClass class from the inner class. What I am trying to do is that the inner class will run on a separate thread and will keep checking the isActive variable on the main class and if isActive is false then it will stop running the new thread.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't have inner classes. Consider making isActive a property of MainClass, give InnerClass a pointer to an instance of MainClass, and let InnerClass simply access the property.

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C doesn't have inner classes as a language construct, however you can do all sorts of tricky things like hiding both the interface and implementation of the "innerclass" in the .m file of the MainClass and having a hidden factory method (not in the interface) on the MainClass that creates the 'innerclass' with a `bool*` property assigned to `&isActive` of the main class.

**MainClass.h**

```
 @interface MainClass : NSObject{
      BOOL isActive;
 }
 @end
```

**MainClass.m**

```
 @interface InnerClass : NSObject{
      BOOL* isActive;
 }

 -(id)initWithActive:(BOOL*)isAct){

      if (self = [super init]) {
         isActive = isAct;
      } 
      return self;
 }

 @end

 @implementation InnerClass

 -(void)run{
      while(*isActive){//want to access this variable which defined in MainClass
      //do something
      }
 }

 @end


 @implementation MainClass

      //Can use [self newInnerClass] to create a new instance of the innerclass
     -(id)newInnerClass{
           return [[[InnerClass alloc] initWithActive:&isActive] autorelease];
      }


 @end
```

Comment: Could you write a little bit of code? I don't understand what you mean by a hidden factory method...

Comment: I just mean a a Method that sets up the instance and not shown in the interface. added code.

Comment: Quite a clever solution I think. I do wonder, though, if this is somehow doing things the 'not Objective-C way'. There has to be some more general way of defining small utility classes or something similar. Or is it to have everything in delegate methods? Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, I'm quite new at Objective-C.