# Problems referencing iVar in inner class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, inner-classes

I have a class called `MyClass` which has a small nested inner class called `MyInnerClass`.  The implementation file looks like the following (and also contains an ivar of the nested inner class) :

```
@class MyInnerClass;

@interface MyClass
{
MyInnerClass *myInnerClassIvar;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyInnerClass *myInnerClassIvar;

@end
```

Then in the implementation file, I implement both `MyClass` and `MyInnerClass`. Looks like the following:

```
@interface MyInnerClass
{
iVar *x;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) iVar *x;
@end

@implementation MyInnerClass
@synthesize x;
...
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myInnerClassIvar;
...
@end
```

I am now creating a subclass for `MyClass`, and in it I'm trying to make a call like this:

```
self.myInnerClassIvar.x
```

And I'm getting the following message:

```
Property x cannot be found in in forward class object MyInnerClass *
```

Am I forgetting something? Haven't implemented an inner class before, see no reason why this shouldn't work.

UPDATED: I moved the interface of MyInnerClass to the .h of MyClass and everything works. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Have you tried accessing it through the bracket notation ( `[myInnerClassIvar x]`)? Also your defined and synthesized types are different (`iVar x` and `iVar *x`)

Comment: Accessing it through the bracket seems to work, though it's still putting a warning: "x is deprecated". It's just being really weird. As for the synthesized types being different, that was just a mistake by me when I type this out (I fixed it).

Comment: That deprecation warning is strange, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the interface of MyInnerClass into the .h file of MyClass like following:

MyClass.h

```
@class MyInnerClass;

@interface MyClass
{
MyInnerClass *myInnerClassIvar;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyInnerClass *myInnerClassIvar;

@end

@interface MyInnerClass
{
iVar *x;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) iVar *x;
@end
```

I'll wait before I check this off as the answer because based on the previous answer, I know there is some skepticism. The only reason I tried this is because I saw it in the Apple example SimpleTextInput, except in that one the entire inner class is in the .m file. Anyway, would be interested to hear what people have to say about this, if it might incur unwanted side effects later or if its ok.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Objective-C does not have inner classes in the sense that you are trying to implement. See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5334480/741626). But regarding your question...

in MyClass.h there is no mention of the iVars of MyInnerClass - it is a forward definition, i.e. @class MyInnerClass therefore MySubClass has no reference point for x.

If you define two classes MyClass & MyInnerClass (probably a bad thing to name it that considering...) - have them in two separate .h files and two separate .m files (ie. as normal). Make an @property in MyClass of type MyInnerClass. Then in MySubClass you need to import both MyClass & MyInnerClass.

Comment: This is correct. In simpler terms, your subclass implementation can only see what is defined in your .h file, and all the details of your inner class are in the .m file.

Comment: I actually moved the interface of MyInnerClass into the .h file of MyClass and everything works fine now...just don't know how advisable this is LOL