# How to implement nested classes in objective-c like Java?

Tags: java, objective-c

I need to implement nested  classes. How do I write it in objective-c?
For example, I have such code:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    private B b;

    class B {
        private int z;
        public void f() {
            a = 1;
        }
    }

    public void fA() {
        b.f();
    }
}
```

How can I implement this code in objective-c??

Answer (score 6):

You can't, as there aren't nested classes in Objective-C. Your `A` class could build the `B` class dynamically then register it with the runtime, but there doesn't seem much point as this isn't a natural idiom for the Objective-C language. Just create a normal class that isn't used outside your class.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, Objective-C doesn't have inner classes.. Try these links where this question has been asked before:

[How to access a variable from inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334428/how-to-access-a-variable-from-inner-class)

[Private classes in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682673/private-classes-in-objective-c)

http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2004/Dec/msg00041.html